# How to update a field using Salesforce Developer Console

Tags: soql, developer-console

I can use the Salesforce Developer Console to perform query.

How do I actually update a value.  When I attempt to do it, the message states:

```
The query has to start with 'Find' or 'Select'
```

Is this not possible in the Salesforce Developer Console.

Answer (score 3):

In developer console if you include id in your soql and your profile has edit permission click on that column and edit the  value it will show a small red flag then click save button. You can do from work bench as well.

Answer (score 1):

SOQL is always read-only, in the Developer Console or elsewhere.

You can execute Anonymous Apex from the Developer Console to change data by performing DML operations as you would in other Apex. Be aware that this is quite risky. Running a delete operation on Account without appropriate filters will wipe your production.

It's important to note that Anonymous Apex executes in user mode, which means that security settings are enforced in ways they are not in normal Apex.

Answer (score 1):

After [executing a query in the developer console](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=code_dev_console_tab_query_editor_soql_sosl.htm&type=5), you can edit records in the result set.

Per the [Query Results Grid](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=code_dev_console_tab_query_editor_query_results_grid.htm&type=5) documentation:

> To edit a record within the Query Results grid, double-click the row. Make your changes and click Save Rows.